# Laravel group by not working if only one key exists?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this following code:

```
        $groupedRates = $result->rates->groupBy('minimum_age');
```

when I try to return it, I get this:

```
  "rates": [
                [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "cpf_scheme_id": 1,
                        "minimum_age": 0,
                        "minimum_wage": 0,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "cpf_scheme_id": 1,
                        "minimum_age": 0,
                        "minimum_wage": 750,
                    }
                ]
            ]
```

however, if I were to add one more key, it returns an associative array as expected.

```
  "rates": {
                "0": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "cpf_scheme_id": 1,
                        "minimum_age": 0,
                        "minimum_wage": 0,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "cpf_scheme_id": 1,
                        "minimum_age": 0,
                        "minimum_wage": 750,
                    }
                ],
                "50": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "cpf_scheme_id": 1,
                        "minimum_age": 50,
                        "minimum_wage": 100,
                    }
                ]
            }
```

How do I fix this? It will break apis if it returns an associative array sometimes and a normal array other times!

Comment: Query is working fine as per your code. In your first response there is 2 records with the same minimum_age that is 0 that's why it will return single array but in your second response there is a 2 diff ages like 0 and 50 so it is return an associative array

Comment: but what if I want it to always have a key regardless? Is it possible?